# How to make relative position work like fixed position on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a top navbar which I keep fixed to top using JavaScript.

```css
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#nav').css({top: $(window).scrollTop()});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">My nav</div>
```

I have a problem on my iPhone because when I scroll down the nav disappears and after that when I take off my finger from the touchscreen the nav appears again.

I tried to use `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` events to trigger between fixed/relative position for my nav but it still doesn't work right. (The thing is that when I don't touch the screen with my finger, the nav should be relative)

Is there any other way to fix this problem without using `position: fixed`?

Comment: I tried that but the effect it's not smooth at all it is shaking. And another problem is that you drag the screen and take off the finger while the screen continues to scroll down, meaning tha the touchmove event it's not trigger anymore and the nav is left behind.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to avoid using position:fixed;? I believe I'm doing what you're trying to accomplish on my site (ShoutDRIVE.com) using that method, and it seems to work pretty smoothly on all platforms. I'd try to avoid constantly updating the top property if possible.

Comment: Yes there is a reason why i try to avoid position fixed. I am using another plugin, a left side bar witch pushed the page in the right direction and i have some issues with the fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation disapear when you scroll, because on touch devices, it only calculates the scrollTop when you let go of scrolling. Same go with js handled sticky navigations. 
Have you tried

```
position :sticky;
top:0;
```

I used this as a fallback for position fixed/js positionning on iphone, 
for the same reason as you.